# Python - Chess Board - For loop does not go over all keys in a dictionary because it returns True too early

Tags: python

I've been learning Python for a few weeks now and it's my first programming language.

I'm trying to build a chess board validator. Among other things, this validator should check if the chess piece is on a valid space on the chess board.

[image]

For this, I'm using a dictionary and regular expressions.

```
import re

chessBoard4 = { '8a': 'brook','8b': 'bknight', '8c': 'bbishop', '8d': 'bqueen', '8e': 'bking', '8f': 'bbishop', '8g': 'bknight', '8h': 'brook',
                '7a': 'bpawn','7b': 'bpawn', '7c': 'bpawn', '7d': 'bpawn', '7e': 'bpawn', '7f': 'bpawn', '7g': 'bpawn', '7h': 'bpawn',
                '2a': 'wpawn','2b': 'wpawn', '2c': 'wpawn', '2d': 'wpawn', '2e': 'wpawn', '2f': 'wpawn', '2g': 'wpawn', '2h': 'wpawn', '2h': 'wpawn', '2i': 'wpawn',
                '1a': 'wrook','1b': 'wknight', '1c': 'wbishop', '1d': 'wqueen', '1e': 'wking', '1f': 'wbishop', '1g': 'wknight', '1h': 'wrook'}

def isValidChessBoard(dictionary):

    def isValidSpace():
        for space in dictionary.keys():
            is_match = re.findall("[0-8][a-h]", space)
            if is_match:
                return True
            else:
                return False
                break

    if isValidSpace():
        print("Hooray!")
    else:
        print("One or more chess pieces are not on the chess board.")


isValidChessBoard(chessBoard4)
```

Since there is a chess piece that is not in a valid space of the chess board ('2i': 'wpawn'), I want `isValidSpace()` to return `False` and not `True`. I am aware that "if is_match:" returns `True` because the first iteration of the `for loop` returns `True`. But I want the `for loop` to go over all keys in the dictionary so that it can eventually catch the chess piece that is not on the chess board.

I hope I could get my point across, thanks for having a look!

PS: This is a task from [Automate The Boring Stuff With Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter5/). Regular expressions were actually not taught in this chapter yet but I didn't know how else I could solve this (so there is also a good chance my regex could be improved). How could this be solved without regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `isValidSpace` function. Since you need to check multiple requirements and they all need to be valid, you cannot return as soon as you find one that is. However, you are allowed to exist as soon as one isn't. Thus, you need to rewrite it as:

```
def isValidSpace():
    for space in dictionary.keys():
        is_match = re.findall("[0-8][a-h]", space)
        if not is_match:
            return False
    return True
```

As you can see, we cannot return `True` until we have ensured that all positions are matching.

Also, as side note; you can never reach your `break` statement in the function you have written, since you will always return before that. Thus, there is no need for having it there.

Comment: You're right, this fixed it! I think I had trouble understanding what `return` really does - I thought `return` gives a certain value or something and the code would then go back to the next iteration of the loop as usual. This is also why I had the `break` statement (so that it could leave the loop once `is_match` is empty). But `return` leaves the function immediately, that was my error. Thanks a lot!